# How do i call This nodejs function to be used as a JSON object into another function

Tags: json, node.js

I have this variable called categories that is supposed to hold the object returned from the function that is getting value from mysql database
whenever i want to access this variable in order to use it as a JSON object i'm not able to acess the data following is my codes

```
  //this is the variable that is supposed to return a JSON object containing value from mysql
  var categories= function(req,res){
  req.getConnection(function(err,connection){
    if(err){
      console.log('Connection yanze'+err)
    }else{
      connection.query('select * from categories',function(err,results){
        if(err){
          throw err;

        }else{

        return (JSON.stringify(results));

          }
      })
    }
  })
}

app.get('/',function(req,res,next){
  res.render('index',{title:'Voila',category:categories});
 console.log(categories);//whenever i try to print this variable it only prints the name of the variable instead of printing the the content of the object
})
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, like this, you define your variable categories as a function, not as the result of the function.

Try something like this :

```
function getCategories(req,res){
  req.getConnection(function(err,connection){
    if(err){
      console.log('Connection yanze'+err)
    }else{
      connection.query('select * from categories',function(err,results){
        if(err){
          throw err;

        }else{

        return (JSON.stringify(results));

          }
      })
    }
  })
}

var categories = getCategories(req1, res1);
```